# If there any way to add this code to a function?

Tags: python

Can the code marked with comments can be added to a function? If so, how would I do that?

```
import random

random_list = []
list_length = 20

while len(random_list) < list_length:
    random_list.append(random.randint(0,10))

# Add to function below:
index = 0
count = 0

while index < len(random_list):
    if random_list[index] == 9:
        count = count + 1
        index = index + 1
# End of add to function

print random_list
print count
```

Comment: Read the python [tutorial about functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all that code to count the number of `9`'s in the list:

```
count = random_list.count(9)
```

But if you did want to use that code, you could make this function:

```
def count_function(sequence, item):
    index = 0
    count = 0

    while index < len(sequence):
        if sequence[index] == item:
            count = count + 1
        index = index + 1

    return count
```

So your entire script would be:

```
import random


def count_function(sequence, item):
    index = 0
    count = 0

    while index < len(sequence):
        if sequence[index] == item:
            count = count + 1
        index = index + 1

    return count


random_list = []
list_length = 20

while len(random_list) < list_length:
    random_list.append(random.randint(0,10))

count = count_function(random_list, 9)

print random_list
print count
```

**BONUS:**

Here's a better way to implement the function while still not using the built-in `.count()` function, for learning purposes. To be clear though, you *should* use the built-in `.count()` function.

```
def count_function(iterable, item):
    count = 0

    for item_from_iterable in iterable:
        if item_from_iterable == item:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: Thanks Cyphase that was awesome. I am still learning and I just wanted to get an idea on how to that. :)